# My app hangs while being debugged

Tags: delphi, debugging, dll, opengl, delphi-2009

I am using Delphi 2009 on Vista Ultimate 64 bit.

I run my application from within the Delphi IDE, and after some time (a minute or 2) my application will hang.

Looking at the event log, the hang is associated with a thread exiting. It is not the main thread, but a thread that has been started just after the module RSAENH.DLL has been loaded.

The app runs normally outside the debugger.

Further info: the app makes extensive use of OpenGL, including shaders and some OpenGL 3 features.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I still have no idea what the problem was, but it appears to have gone away with Delphi XE

Answer (score 0):

When running the IDE in Vista, the threads view should indicate if a thread is deadlocked and which resources it it waiting for. Check out this blog post on the "Wait Chain Traversal" feature:
[Tiburon Preview: Vista Wait Chain Traversal](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/chrishesik/2008/07/21/34833)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I have checked the Thread Status window, and when the app is hung, all the threads are state Stopped, status Unknown, and there is nothing in the Wait Chain.